# Signature validation failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4 with Asp.net application MVC 4.5.2 when i run the mvc application its comes to identity server 4 and shows login page. then after filling the credentials it validates the credentials and i have taken redirect to my Mvc 5 application, but sometimes i take this error.

```
IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve 
SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
', 
token:
'{"alg":"RS256","kid":"20200ac5c987a7282847568c7d00dc26","typ":"JWT".
{"nbf":1487015385,"exp":1487015685,"iss":"https://localhost:44348","aud":"mvc","nonce":"636226121849994491.YTcxMjQ2ZDQtOWVlNC00MDk3LWJhOGYtYTIxNmM4OGFkZjU3NDFhODgzMWMtMmQ4OS00OTRmLWJiMzAtZWM1NzYyZjM3MTI2","iat":1487015385,"c_hash":"qzzLGWDykED_OIG0-TIF8w","sid":"174a7048a9521e2c99462e9b681553ae","sub":"c880d185-f7a1-422b-8cce-dff8142a1a3b","auth_time":1487014828,"idp":"local","amr":["pwd"]}'.
```

Comment: Are you using the temporary signing credential? Try setting an X509 cert in IS4.

Comment: yes i am using the default temporary signing, let me try the X509.

Comment: @leastprivilege how can i create the X509 cert???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "sometimes" this sounds to me like you are using the `AddTemporarySigningCredentials` option in IdentityServer4.

This means that new key material will get created on each startup of the host.

In your case the MVC application has a cached version of the key material and thus gets out of sync.

Try setting static keys - e.g. using an X509 cert:

https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/

Comment: I had this issue when switching from localhost to external web server - token seemed to be cached so ran incognito mode and all good.