# Signature validation failed when behind a load balancer

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing, identityserver4

I currently have Identity Server 4 running on a single server, runs fine and no issues except for when I put a load balancer (Kemp) in-front of Identity Server 4 I get the following error AFTER authenticating and being rerouted back to one of my applications.

IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier:

```
SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
        IsReadOnly = False,
        Count = 1,
        Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
```

I've reviewed the stack overflow question located here ([Signature validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213351/signature-validation-failed/42242441#42242441)), and I already have an SSL cert installed on both servers sitting behind the load balancer. In addition, I've also read the article located on Dominick's website about setting the public origin, which I have done - that article is located here: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/10/09/new-in-identityserver4-v2-simplified-configuration-behind-load-balancers-or-reverse-proxies/

What's the next step on resolving the error/issue listed above?

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: Can you verify which instance (server) it is hitting when you try to login, and when you are being re-routed. I have the feeling that you have not implemented the `DataProtection` and by this, your server is not stateless.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 - thank you for the reply. I have gone as far shutting one instance down and accessing IDS4, so, I know exactly which instance I'm hitting. I did that in hopes of eliminating perhaps a bad configuration. Unfortunately, I experience the same results on both servers. Can you provide an example of what you are referring to when you say 'DataProtection'?

Comment: are you experiencing the same behavior when only one server is up and running?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 - yes I am.

Comment: That's kinda strange, but anyway - try implementing the DataProtection. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing this, is that you don't preserve the data protection keys. Basically IdentityServer implements an InMemory data protection, but having a load balancer this is not working for you.

What you need to do, is to implement `IXmlRepository` and add your own Data Protection. It is added in the `startup.cs` and is **very important** to add it to the pipeline, after you have added the IdentitiyServer. Something like:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.
.
.more code here (like AddProfileService() etc.)
.
.
```

And then (later in the pipeline), you need:

```
serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
services.AddDataProtection()
    .AddKeyManagementOptions(options =>
    {
        options.XmlRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IXmlRepository>();
    })
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
    .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert)
    .SetApplicationName("Application name");
```

Before that, you need to register in the DI your implementation of the `IXmlRepository`. In my case:

```
services.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository, DataProtectionKeyStore>();
```

Where `DataProtectionKeyStore` is the implementation of the `IXmlRepository`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) are some examples from the official Microsoft docs, for saving this keys, or if you want to use Database, you can implement your own logic too (that's what I did).

All of the above, of course, is if everything with your Cert is OK (as you are saying). But it should be, if it is working when not behind load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance with this, I've implemented a solution as outlined on the Microsoft site you suggested. However, now I'm getting a SocketException (0x274c) error. Not sure if this is related at this point or not, but wanted to let you know I've tried your suggestion(s) - thank you!

Comment: When and where are you getting this exception?

Comment: We're experiencing the exception AFTER we change our DNS to point to the load balancer. We can hit either server directly and login without exception, but as soon as we set the load balancer as the point of entry we get errors.

Comment: If you can hit the servers individually, and login successfully, then the error is not in the IDS. Don't look for it there. Look for an error in the LB configuration